# Converting ArrayAdapter to List

Tags: c#, list, xamarin.android, android-arrayadapter

Is there any direct way to convert `Android.Widget.ArrayAdapter` in Xamarin Android to `System.Collections.Generic.List`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way I can see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.widget.arrayadapter?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

```
using System.Linq;

ArrayAdapter<MyType> arrayAdapter = // some value

List<MyType> list = arrayAdapter.ToArray<MyType>().ToList();
```